# Not able to create super user in Django, Virtualenv

Tags: python, django, eclipse, virtualenv

I'm trying to create superuser in django but keep getting this error message.

```
Superuser creation skipped due to not running in a TTY. You can run `manage.py createsuperuser` in your project to create one manually.
```

I tried eclipse custom command first and than I saw some people able to create super user using window command line with virtualenv, so I installed and activated it. However till now I wasn't able to create superuser. What I've been typing in the cmd is

```
C:\Users\name>python
Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> python manage.py createsuperuser
File "<stdin>", line 1
 python manage.py createsuperuser
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried this too.

```
C:\Users\name>python manage.py createsuperuser
python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: You need to run the command in the right directory..

Comment: The command should be run outside the Python shell: `$ python manage.py createsuperuser`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command to create a superuser from terminal is,

`python manage.py createsuperuser`

But you have to run this command from the django project directory. The fact that manage.py can't be found means you are not in the project directory. You have to first cd into it.

Answer (score 1):

you are creating super user inside the python console. don't do like that. go to the location where manage.py is located via cmd and run the command. then you can create the super user.

Answer (score 1):

Run this command from your project directory

```
[projectname]/
├── [appname]/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── manage.py
```

here you should run this from projectname directory.

Answer (score 0):

use this command :

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations

python3 manage.py migrate

python3 manage.py createsuperuser

python manage.py runserver
```

your error I guess is : [Error `You have 14 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, content types, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 303, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)`][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8Wxv.png)

check you yo directory with Tree command:[`tree`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43mGL.png)

Then run Make migration :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnQMr.png)

then create superuser with the `python3 manage.py createsuperuser`command :